# Cross join a users table to add a "next_updated_at" for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I essentially want to find the “next_updated_at” for each user_id

The Users tables important fields are user_id, id, updated_at

My thought was to try to cross join the users table to find the minimum updated_at for each user_id where the joined tables id is greater than the main tables id

```
SELECT * FROM users m1

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT min(updated_at),user_id FROM users GROUP BY user_id
) m2 ON m2.user_id = m1.user_id AND m2.id > m1.id
```

But id doesn’t exist in the subquery… I’m kind of stumped

Users Table

```
user_id     id  updated_at
12345       1   01-01-2018
12345       2   03-05-2018
11223       3   03-07-2018
33211       4   04-11-2018
11223       5   06-11-2018
11223       6   11-01-2018
33211       7   01-04-2019
33211       8   01-07-2019
```

Desired Query

```
user_id     id  updated_at  next_updated_at
12345       1   01-01-2018  03-05-2018
12345       2   03-05-2018  
11223       3   03-07-2018  06-11-2018
33211       4   04-11-2018  01-04-2019
11223       5   06-11-2018  11-01-2018
11223       6   11-01-2018
33211       7   01-04-2019  01-07-2019
33211       8   01-07-2019
```

Comment: I don't think the group and min is helping there, do it the other way (join then group/min). Or leverage the LEAD analytic function if your Postgres/redshift supports it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
SELECT u.*,
       LEAD(updated_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY updated_at, id) as next_updated_at
FROM users u;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to use the `id`.  It seems that the next updated would be based on the date itself.  I added the `id` to handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the redshift flavour of PG supports simple analytic functions like lead:

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  id,
  updated_at, 
  LEAD(updated_at) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id) as next_updated_at
FROM users
```

Lead selects the updated_at from the next row (order defined by ID, could have used updated_at as well/instead) within the same set of user_id (the partition means every distinct user id  works as a set)

I conceive mentally that LEAD breaks the result set up into groups of user ids ordered by date, and then for any given row, the lead row is the next one after it. It's actually a bit more like analytic functions establish a separate, possibly grouped, coordinated result set that is automatically associated with the current row in some way.. but whatever helps your mental model :)

Going your way something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.user_id,
  a.id,
  a.updated_at,
  min(z.updated_at)
FROM
  users a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  users z ON a.user_id = z.userid and a.id < z.id
GROUP BY 
  a.user_id,
  a.id,
  a.updated_at
```

This joins all rows from a user to all other rows of the same user where the id is greater, then uses grouping to find only the min greater id per other id from that same user

Users table:

```
user_id     id  updated_at
11223       3   03-07-2018
11223       5   06-11-2018
11223       6   11-01-2018
```

After self join on userid and id

```
a.userid a.id a.updated_at z.userid z.id z.updatedat
11223       3   03-07-2018 11223       5 06-11-2018
11223       3   03-07-2018 11223       6 11-01-2018
11223       5   06-11-2018 11223       6 11-01-2018
11223       6   11-01-2018
```

Then the group by min zaps the later rows (row 2)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be perhaps the easiest and quite possibly the most performant query and avoids using `PARTITION BY`.

```
SELECT 
 o.user_id
,o.id
,o.updated_at
,(SELECT TOP 1 i.updated_at FROM users i WHERE i.user_id = o.user_id AND i.updated_at > o.updated_at ORDER BY i.updated_at ASC) AS next_updated_at
FROM users o
```

Comment: You'd rather use a "select subquery in the main select list" than an analytic? Curious to know why that is!?

Comment: Some of those analytic operations are more intensive on CPU and server performance. i believe the database engine will produce a simpler plan with that's more resourceful.

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-and-subquery/)

Comment: BTW: did this help with what you wanted to do?